# Can I make an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary, uipickerview

Im trying to create an array inside an array inside an array. Then use a UIPickerView with 3 components, each for the respective array. The reason I used arrays is because the data is organized like this:

```
var array1 = [
     "2"
[       "2"
           ["2.5","2.5"],
        "1-1/12"
           ["2.5","2.375"]],
     "3"
[       "2-1/2"
           ["3.375", "3.25"],
[       "2"
           ["3.375", "3"]]]
```

I've tried making dictionaries to call from (easier for UIPickerView) but the [(key:value)] combo won't work with tuples.

```
var dict: [(size: String, outlets: (outlet1: String, measure1: String, measure2: String))] = [
("2", ("1-1/2","2.5","2.375"))
]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 3
}
```

There's not much info about arrays inside arrays or dicts inside dicts.

The source data is from a chart that looks like this:

```
          --> outlet1 --> value1, value2
size1 --> --> outlet2 --> value1, value2
          --> outlet3 --> value1, value2

          --> outlet1 --> value1, value2
size2 --> 
          --> outlet2 --> value1, value2
```

Outlets can be the same `String` as size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

You want a dictionary where the `key` is a String, and the `value` is a custom structure containing an outlet and two measures.

Start by creating a structure for the custom structure:

```
struct Outlet {
    var outlet1: String = ""
    var measure1: String = ""
    var measure2: String = ""
}
```

then create an `outlet` and set its properties:

```
var myOutlet = Outlet()
myOutlet.outlet1 = "1-1/2"
myOutlet.measure1 = "2.5"
myOutlet.measure2 = "2.375"
```

and add an array of them to the dictionary:

```
var dict = ["2" : [myOutlet]]
```

or define the dictionary and set the value

```
var dict: [ String : [Outlet] ]
dict["2"] = [myOutlet]
```

Comment: do you mind clicking the Upvote or the Solved button?